# Display menus in appbar right

Tags: java, android, material-design

HI am learning material design and i have created an appbar. When i add items to main_menu its displays in the drop down, but i want it to display a new icon just before the settings icon in app bar.

**My app**

[image]
[image]

1) I want to add the icon just next the settings icon. But now it shows in the dropdown box when i click on settings icon.

**Main Menu**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:title="@string/favourite"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        />

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.favorite){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 <item android:id="@+id/favorite"
    android:title="@string/favourite"        
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@mipmap/options"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_my_music"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="My music" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_friends"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="Friend`s music" />            
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way android provides to set app icon at right side of actionbar but you can still do that.**

Create a menu, say main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/your_app_icon"
    android:title="@string/menu_item"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>  //set showAsAction always
                                //and this should be the only menu item with show as action always

</menu>
```

Now just override onCreateOptionsMenu in your class file.

add this in MainActivity.class

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

It's done! Your app icon will be visible on right side of ActionBar now.

Comment: Tnx. I dont want to set the app icon to right. i just want the menu and the icon to be displayed in right. i updated the question plz check.